# An idiom expressing the circularity of tool making

Tags: idioms, proverbs

Is there an idiom or a proverb like "in order to make a knife you need to use another knife", or, better, "in order to make a sharp knife you need to use a duller knife", expressing the fact that tools are made with the aid of similar, less refined, tools?

Comment: Well, [there's a hole in the bucket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wNN-qAselM) is a song about tool circularity.

Comment: Nice question. "What goes around comes around" is the first that comes to mind, about circularity in general. I don't think it fits, though.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant idiom here is...

> [***Pull yourself up by your [own] bootstraps***](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/pull-yourself-up-by-your-bootstraps-nonsense_n_5b1ed024e4b0bbb7a0e037d4?ri18n=true&guccounter=1)

...where you might find that Huffington Post article interesting. I haven't read it all, so I don't know whether it explicitly points out that this idiomatic usage has been modified / transferred to the IT world - when your computer ***boots up***, that's just a shorter way of saying it's ***bootstrapping** [itself, the Operating System]*.

---

I only discovered after writing the above that the increasingly popular [GRUB boot loader package](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) is an initialism standing for *GRand Unified **Bootloader***. I suspect metaphoric ***booting up*** may extend even further in future, as we get used to the idea that even things like TVs take time to "turn on" these days (because they're basically "computers").

Comment: In British English "Pull yourself up by your [own] bootstraps" means to improve yourself, and/or your position in life, by the use of your own resources.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an idiom or a proverb like "in order to make a knife you need to use another knife"

"You need a knife if you want to make a knife - **It's turtles all the way down**"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down

> "Turtles all the way down" is an expression of the problem of [infinite regress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_regress). The saying alludes to the mythological idea of a World Turtle that supports the flat earth on its back. It suggests that this turtle rests on the back of an even larger turtle, which itself is part of a column of increasingly large world turtles that continues indefinitely (i.e., "turtles all the way down").

Comment: I don't see the quote "You need a knife if you want to make a knife" in the Wikipedia page you linked to.

Comment: @EvanAad You will also note that it is not formatted as a quote from the Wiki page. It is a sentence I produced myself by way of an example. :)